# Redirecting an entire directory excluding one particular url string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Greets:

I have an old piece of code in a /work directory that I have to keep there. I'd like to redirect all requests to the /work directory to the site root, *except for url's that look like this:
/work/index.php?option=com_career&view=career &
/work/administrator
How would I go about doing this in .htaccess?

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# pass through this URL unchanged
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_career&view=career
RewriteRule ^work/index\.php$ - [L]

# pass through this URL unchanged
RewriteRule ^work/administrator - [L]

# redirect everything else
RewriteRule ^work/ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The option=com and administrator appear to work, but the /work/whatever other than option=com and administrator don't redirect to site root? What would the syntax be to redirect to the url (main)?

Comment: @ChristopherS.Beard the last line is what does the redirect, and it's redirecting to `/`, you can replace that with `http://whatever.domain.com/` if you want, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thanks Jon. It's not working. /work url's are still clickable (i.e.not redirecting).

Comment: Jon..it ended up working. Helps if you edit the .htaccess in your root directory, not your /work directory ;) Thanks so much.